# Can 'where's this coming from' mean 'why do you say this'?

Tags: sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

If someone say something to you, and you wonder why they say that out of the blue, is it natural to ask 'where's this coming from'?

For example, Alan and Betty's relationship gradually gets better and better. Betty secretly loves Alan, although Alan is unaware of this and just treats Betty as a good friend. But their first encounter was quite a calamitous one- due to an accident, Betty took Alan as a groper. Then, one day, when they are hanging out, this dialogue begins.

> Betty: I have to say, our first encounter really was horrible.
>
> Alan: Where's this coming from?

Is 'where's this coming from' what a native speaker would say in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Where's this coming from?' sounds like a more specific version of 'Why do you say this?' in the sense that what is being asked about is maybe out of the blue or that the asker doesn't really understand the relevance to the discussion.